# Generating a sequence number based on last item of a list

Tags: c#, parsing, formatting

I wrote this method in order to generate a sequence number based on a specific pattern:

```
public string LatestNumber(Guid id = default(Guid))
{
    var number = "";
    if (id == Guid.Empty)
    {
        var items = myList.ToList();
        var lastNumber = items.Any() ? items[items.Count - 1].Number : "";

        var intitialNumber = "Number#000001";
        if (!items.Any())
            number = intitialNumber;
        else
        {
            var nextNumber = int.Parse(lastNumber.Split('#')[1]) + 1;
            number = $"Number#{nextNumber:D6}";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        number = myList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id).Number;
    }

    return number;
}
```

This code works as expected in production but I wonder if there's a better way to make this code clean or more testable. What do you think?

Comment: I get this is code review but what is requirements here?   This seems like an odd design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do differently.

- `number` - this variable is not necessary, you can return anytime
- `myList` - if this is already a list then you don't need to copy it
- `lastNumber` - this is initialized too early. It should be placed inside `else`
- `if` - don't ommit the `{}`
- `!items.Any()` and `items.Any()` - you don't need to check it twice and even with different results
- `: ""` - this value is never used because you don't enter the first `else` if `myList.Any()` - in this case you use `.Number` and the only place where you use the resulting `lastNumber` is the first `else`
- `[1]` - you should name this index
- `intitialNumber` - define this as a constant

---

> ```
> number = myList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id).Number;
> ```

You know that this might blow? If the list is empty then the `Number` cannot be read. You need either C# 6 for this or one more line of code.

---

Putting everything together gives:

```
const string intitialNumber = "Number#000001";

if (id == Guid.Empty)
{
    if(myList.Any())
    {
        const int someMagicValue = 1;
        var lastNumber = myList.Last().Number; // Last is O(1) for IList
        var nextNumber = int.Parse(lastNumber.Split('#')[someMagicValue]) + 1;
        return = $"Number#{nextNumber:D6}";
    }
    else
    {
        return intitialNumber;
    }
}
else
{
    var first = myList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    return first != null ? first.Number : intitialNumber;

    // C# 6
    // myList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)?.Number ?? intitialNumber;
}
```

Comment: initialNumber is not defined

Comment: No it is not obvious to me.  In the OP code it is var intitialNumber = "Number#000001";   No need for the snark.  I will remember to just stay off your posts in the future.

Comment: @Paparazzi haha, my bad, I somehow overlooked that this one was missing

Comment: Not the first time you have snapped at me when my comment was valid.

Comment: @Paparazzi that's true and I apologize for this. I'll try to make an effort so there is no next time ;-)